# starting pentaho CE as windows service

Tags: tomcat, windows-services, pentaho, tomcat8

I am trying to start Pentaho Community Edition as a WINDOWS SERVICE, but its not helping, i have tried the steps defined in the article [Starting BI Server as a windows service](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Starting+BI+Server+as+a+windows+service)

But executing the command `service install` gives the error **"Failed installing 'Tomcat8' service"**

Please if anyone can guide me what am doing wrong here??? I think the above article is for an Enterprise Edition?

Is it possible to execute the batch file start-pentaho.bat when the windows start? :(

Answer (score 1):

These are the checks I made and documented when installing BI server as a service:

NOTE: *I am using Pentaho 5.4 Enterprise edition and the checks might be useful for the other editions too.*

- Check if your environment variables point to JDK 7.
- Check if you have a variable PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME defined in the user
  and system variable sections, point to the java inside the Pentaho
  folder.
- In the System Variables your JAVA_HOME variable should point to this
  path C:\Program Files\JAVA\jdk1.7.0_51
- Add a Variable called JRE_HOME pointing to C:\Program
  Files\JAVA\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
- Make sure you have PENTAHO_INSTALLED_LICENSE_PATH and PENTAHO_HOME
  variables.
- Go to the Services and check if you have a service called Apache
  Tomcat 6.0. If not, we have to install the service first. See the
  next point.
- Follow this link to install the service manually: 
  http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Starting+BI+Server+as+a+windows+service

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

which version of pentaho bi server are you using?
I'm able to install 6.1.0.1-196.

`biserver-ce\tomcat\bin\service.bat install BIServer`

Then the service is visible.

Are you able to run the bi server via start-pentaho.bat?

But in my case the service starts, but I cannot login. I get an `PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014`